# iteration/expansion method solution required

Tags: iteration, expansion

Can anybody help me to Solve the following recurrence using iteration/expansion method?

```
1.T(n)= T(n-1)+ n,T(0)= 1
```

The solution should be like this way

```
T(k)=T(K-1)+K

T(K-1)=T(K-2)+(K-1)

......................
```

Comment: this sounds like a home work; if so think your self, and ask when got stuck; else please clearify

Comment: got stuck in the last line for the question 1.the form i found after solution is T(k)=1+1+2+3...... which does not belongs to any series!

Comment: this sounds like [fibionacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), but i still dont get the question, or was that you question -> fibionacci

Comment: no my question was not fibionacci! but i would not mind if the resultant series forms a fibionacci series.my target is to expand the equation using iteration/expansion method such a way so that i get a non recurrence form!

Comment: oh I need glasses, I read 1,1,2,3 instead of 1+1+2+3, sry, answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so given is:

```
1. T(n)= T(n-1) + n
2. T(0)= 1
```

so it gets like this:

```
T(0) = 1
T(1) = T(0) + 1 = 2
T(2) = T(1) + 2 = 4
T(3) = T(2) + 3 = 7
T(4) = T(3) + 4 = 11
T(5) = T(4) + 5 = 16
```

if you look closer it is:

```
T(k) = sum(k) +1    // sum(k)=1+2+3+4+5 ... + k-1+k
```

Take a look at Gauss [The sum of all natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%E2%8B%AF), he told us, that sum(k)=(k^2+k)/2

so your solution should be:

```
T(k) = 1 + (k^2+k)/2
```